# Match erroneos en Regex

Tags: regex

alguien sabe como mejorar esta regex para que funcione correctamente?, les explico
el usuario puede escribir una linea de código y mi analizador léxico debe de crear los tokkens, con esta regex identifico todos los identificadores y tipos de datos de una linea sin hacer split:

```
[A-z$_][\w]*
```

pero esta regex no funciona correctamente cuando tenemos una linea asi:

```
string 45x="Hola"
```

el 45  me lo marca como incorrecto pero la x si y lo que quiero es que todo lo que viene siendo 45x lo marque erróneo al igual el Hola no debe de ser marcado como identificador ya que debería ser una literal de cadena

intente hacer un split en espacios en blanco para dividir cada componente y verificarlos cada uno por separado pero seria erroneo si tengo una literal de cadena con espacios:

```
string x = "Hola Mundo"
y="Hola      Mundo"
```

[aqui un ejemplo](https://regex101.com/r/LAKxvM/1)

nota: deben de haber obligatoriamente espacios cuando no es seguido de operadores como + = , ; etc..
ejemplo:

```
string[espacio]identificador[Puede tener ningun espacio o muchos]=[Puede tener ningun espacio o 
muchos]identificador[Puede tener ningun espacio o muchos];
```